# Send Auth token and payload in POST Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, server, tornado

How can I send the authorization token and payload data with a post call in tornado? I'm trying to make a request to  a  url. Normally the access token is passed in the headers like this :

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But How can I do this with tornado. I'm trying to code a very simple example that just sends payload and auth in the post request and gets a response.

How can I adjust the auth token in the headers?
The docs are a bit hard for me to understand. I've just starting to learn tornado and am not very proficient in it.

**EDIT**:

The code I tried :

```
class ResquestsAPIs(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post():
        self.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        self.baseUrl = "url to send request to"
  
        headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        body = urllib.parse.urlencode({
            "data": "test",
       
        })  
 
        response = http_client.fetch(self.baseUrl, method='POST', 
                                  headers=headers, body=body)
        print(response)
```

Comment: Are trying to send a request **to** your Tornado server or **from** your Tornado server to another server?

Comment: From my tornado server to another

Comment: Could you add your code that you've tried to send a request with?

Comment: Please see the edit @DelenaMalan

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders` class to make headers.

```py
headers = HTTPHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"})
headers.add("Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
headers.add("Accept": "application/json")
```